# Prepare for segue SearchDisplayController with Parse.com

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, uisearchdisplaycontroller

in my app I'm using Parse.com as the holder of the data on a database and SearchBarDisplayController for research. I have prepared a following to prepare for my table in order to send the data cells in another view controller and works perfectly ... Now I am having a problem ...

How can I create a "prepareforsegue" for the SearchDisplayController, to activate the cells of the search results?

In here you can see the code for "Prepare for Segue" (or another Method) that I made and the data to be passed ...

Some Ideas on this? Thanks so much!

```
#import "Ricerca.h"
#import "Custom.h"
#import "DettagliProfilo.h"

@interface Ricerca () <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

@end

@implementation Ricerca
@synthesize searchResults;




- (void)viewDidLoad {


 [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadObjects];
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"_User";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;
       self.objectsPerPage = 10;
    }
    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    //[query whereKeyExists:@"username"];
    //[query whereKeyExists:@"email"];
    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];

    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    return query;
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {



    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }


    // Configure the cell

    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = color;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = color;


    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"username"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"email"];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown"];
        PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"foto"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];


        }];

    }

    else if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {


        PFObject *searchedUser = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *content = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"username"];
        NSString *email = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"email"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = email;
        cell.textLabel.text = content;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown"];
        PFFile *imageFile = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"foto"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];


        }];


        NSLog(@"Content: %@", content);


    }

    return cell;

}
- (void)callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:(NSArray *)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error) {

        [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

        NSLog(@"Successfully fetched %d entries", result.count);

        [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:result];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

}


-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"email"];
    [query whereKey:@"username" containsString:searchTerm];
     query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:error:)];
  }




-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {

    [self filterResults:searchString];

    return YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.rowHeight = 80.0f; // or some other height
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return self.objects.count;

    } else {
        return self.searchResults.count;
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    } else {

        [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}



- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Check that a new transition has been requested to the DetailViewController and prepares for it

        /*if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Dettaglio"]){

        // Capture the object (e.g. exam) the user has selected from the list
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        DettagliProfilo *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.Dettaglio = object;*/

    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"Dettaglio"])
    {
        DettagliProfilo *sdvc = (DettagliProfilo *)[segue destinationViewController];


        if(self.searchDisplayController.active) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
            PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            object = (PFObject *)[[self searchResults]objectAtIndex:[[[[self searchDisplayController]searchResultsTableView]indexPathForSelectedRow]row]];
            sdvc.Dettaglio = object;

        }   else {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            DettagliProfilo *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
            detailViewController.Dettaglio = object;


        }

    } 
}
@end
```

Comment: Hello to all! I solved ... I'll post the code of the file. M - (Edited in the original)


Can you tell me if you think something is missing what?
The research seems to be fine but every so often, not always, the Log gives me this warning and automatically slows down the search ...

This is the Alert : 2013-09-17 11:19:42.752 SearchBar_Tutorial[4884:60b] Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug

What did I miss??

Comment: The warning states _A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug_ have you tried doing this? When you hit the breakpoint you should be able to check your stack to see where the call came from. I had a quick glance through your code, and couldn't see where this might be happening (you are using the "find in background" selectors appropriately, perhaps somewhere else in your application you have accidentally used a blocking function.

Comment: Ahar Hello, thank you for your intervention ... The problem is that ... No further queries currently in that project and do not understand where it could be the problem ...

I was born a doubt ... Could be the profile picture of the users to be too heavy and slow down everything?

Comment: Rory - I think you missed my main point, and the point being stated in the warning message from Parse - have you set a break point on that function? This will allow you to identify your problem immediately. If you were downloading a profile large image, this shouldn't cause the above message.

Comment: forgive me I did not understand ... I have a bad English . I now do the checks as you suggested